# Rails 4 authenticate method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I bought the book "Beginning Rails 4" on Apress and it uses `user.authenticate` for authentication, however it throws me an error. Afterwards I read a review saying that the book mainly covers Rails 3.2, so is this no longer supported?

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `authenticate' for #<Class:0x007f83ece1a678>

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
        else
```

My sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password combination"
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        reset_session
        redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You successfully logged out"
    end
end
```

View

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<%= form_tag session_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you also paste your `User` model? Does it has a class method `authenticate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the bcrypt-ruby gem.

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

In your user model, you need to add:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  ...
end
```

Make sure to migrate `rake db:migrate` and to restart server

Comment: It worked! Thanks mate, I was starting to get headaches of this. :D

Comment: Haha.. No prob :-) Best of luck with rails!

Answer (score 1):

Try in the create method:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
```

...

Notice: authenticate applies to instance variable.